# Trying to fetch the api but react gives an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch the data of an api but there's a problem that occurs all the time. I have a function to set the data to the new one once the fetching process is over and I'm trying to call it as a callback. Here's the code:

The function where I fetch the data:

```
async function getAPI(url, settings, callback) {
    const response = await fetch(url, settings)
    var result = await response.json()
    callback(result)
}
```

Where I use it:

```
const callback = (newVal) => {
    // Return if newVal === ""
    if (newVal === "") {
        return
    }
    // Delete the previous data & set the new searchVal
    setData(null)
    setSearchVal(newVal)

    // Get API
    const url = `https://movies-tvshows-data-imdb.p.rapidapi.com/?type=get-movies-by-title&title=${newVal}`
    const settings = {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-key": "xyz",
            "x-rapidapi-host": "movies-tvshows-data-imdb.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
    }

    getAPI(url, settings, setData)
}
```

Where I call the callback(by the way, callback is called correctly as I already have done the debugging for that part):

```
return (
    <div id="movie-page">
        <MovieBar callback={(val)=>{callback(val)}} />
    </div>
)
```

If you think that there's no error here and maybe there's something else in the code that does cause it, please do comment it so that I'll update the question. Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE 1:

I also wanted to add my initial declarations, here they are:

```
const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState(null)
const [searchOn, setSearchOn] = useState(false)
const [scene, setScene] = useState(null)
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
```

By the way, I haven't started working on some of them. So keep that in mind.

Comment: can you add more information about the problem that occurs? maybe a console error. Also may be a good idea to censor your api key in the x-rapidapi-key header if it is sensitive.

Comment: This is the error I get: TypeError: Object(_helpers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["getAPI"]) is not a function. (In 'Object(_helpers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["getAPI"])(url, settings, setData)', 'Object(_helpers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["getAPI"])' is an instance of Object)

Comment: I have no idea what this error is about

Comment: can you post how you are importing & exporting the getAPI method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I missed this one, I just forgot to export the function.

Here's the initial code where I export the function:

```
async function getAPI(url, settings, callback) {
    const response = await fetch(url, settings)
    var result = await response.json()
    callback(result)
}
```

I just added `export` at the beginning and that's it.